# On page reload, check boxes get selected and then disappear automatically within a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, onclick

I have a problem with a function that i'm writing.
Basically, I'm simulating a landing page. The landing page will contain a querystring. What I'm doing is to deserialize it on a button click and show(to check) the checkboxes defined in the querystring in the HTML.

Below is the click function which contains two functions. 
The first one "simulateLandingPage" performs the url change.
The second one called "selectFacetsAutomatically" deserializes the "landingUrl" path and checks automatically the checkboxes in the HTML page according to what is defined in the querystring.

The problem that I'm encountering is that when I click on the "reload-page" button everything works but the checkboxes get selected just for a second and then disappear automatically quickly without any reason. Hence the page won't show the selected checkboxes in the end but just this weird thing.

Can anyone help? I'm pretty new to this and i'm stuck.
Thanks a lot!

```
$(".reload-page").click(function() {
     var landingUrl = "size:4,10,16|base_colour:1,4|brand:53,3392,12767";
     simulateLandingPage(landingUrl);
     selectFacetsAutomatically(landingUrl);
     return false;  
});

 function simulateLandingPage(landingUrl){
        window.location.href = "refinements.html?refine="+ encodeURIComponent(landingUrl);
        return false;
    }

function selectFacetsAutomatically(landingUrl){

    var facetGroup = [];
    var selectedFacets = [];
    var facetType;

        //split string when it finds the pipe symbol
    $.each(decodeURIComponent(landingUrl).split(/\|/), function (i, val) {

         selectedFacets.push(val);

         console.log("val", selectedFacets[i].split(/\:/)[1].split(/\,/));

         facetType = selectedFacets[i].split(/\:/)[0];
         facetGroup = selectedFacets[i].split(/\:/)[1].split(/\,/);

         $.each(facetGroup, function(i,val){

            var facetToBeSelected = facetType + "_" + val;
            $('[data-id='+facetType+']').find("#"+facetToBeSelected).prop('checked', true);

         });
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: you may need to share with us your HTML or a jsFiddle demo would be even better?

Comment: try using attr('checked', true) instead of prop, sometimes helps

Comment: Hello, I've just tried but nothing. I'm going to attach a jsfiddle example btw.

Comment: Here is the jfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/beppe0/gzfe1q3j/

Comment: @Beppe: could it be that you are using `decodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURIComponent` in the `selectFacetsAutomatically` function?

Comment: @Tahir - thank you for your answer. I'm using decodeUri as I need to use it. I don't see any other way to simulate to decode the URL. I might be wrong though.

Comment: can you quickly try with `encode` please? I could be wrong of course but I just feel like, you don't need to decode but encode.

Comment: I can try but I do encode the URL in the other function and what I need to deserialise the URL before looping through. It seems like the selectFacetsAutomatically function runs first, that's why it gets overwritten. But I don't understand why :/